# C# webBrowser null exception error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

What is wrong with this:

```
webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("http://www.google.com");
MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Url.ToString());
```

When the message box tries to run it complains of a null exception.

I think I may have found the solution to my problem, it seems that I was trying to read the value before it was initalized, once I had checked this it worked perfectly. Noob error. :o(

Comment: Can you post the exact error message, including stack trace?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `webBrowser1` which is null?

Comment: How did you initialize webBrowser1?

Comment: Without an actual stack trace I would bet it is blowing up on the previous line complaining that webBrowser is null. Post the stack trace and we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perhaps not initialize webBrowser1?

```
var webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("http://www.google.com");
MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Url.ToString());
```

Comment: I will mark this answer as accepted, because although I did initialize  webBrowser1, I tried to do things before it *was* initialized.